# How add Condition and function in ng-class

Tags: angularjs

```
<!--<li ng-class="{active: aba == 1,  disabled: autenticarAcessoAba(1) }">-->

 <li ng-class="{'active': aba =='2'  , disabled: autenticarAcessoAba(2) && !aba=='2' }">

  $scope.autenticarAcessoAba = function(aba){
        return aba > $scope.ultimaAba;//setar disabled como class

}
```

I am control 'aba', active and disable others 'aba'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function should return `true` or `false` and you add it to the `ngClass` expression

```
<li ng-class="{active: aba == 1 && !myFunc(1), disabled: myFunc(1)}">

$scope.myFunc= function(aba){
   return aba > $scope.ultimaAba;
}
```

Comment: instead of `function` there should be other name, as its conflicts with `function` reserved keyword..

Comment: @PankajParkar - Updated my answer

Comment: I make this, but not success.. =/

Comment: @ArthurGonçalves - have you tried it it after I updated my answer? You should be more specific with what's doesn't work.

Comment: @ArthurGonçalves - I added my last attempt to help because it's very difficult for me to understand your requirements. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Alon when I set a value aba == 1 how I execut the function again?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
ng-class="{'active': condition,disabled: functionWhichDecidesTruthyOrFalse(1)}"
```

Comment: I need add 2 class, the first with conditional and second with result of function